# How to completely hide nohup messages?

Tags: bash

I try to completely hide nohup messages from my terminal. My nohup usage looks like this:

```
if eval 'nohup grep "'$arg1' '$arg2' [A-Za-z]\+" /tmp/dict.txt >& /dev/null &'; then
```

but in console I get one nohup message in Polish:

```
nohup: zignorowanie wejścia i przekierowanie standardowego błędu do standardowego wyjścia
```

which means "ignoring standard input redirecting standard error to standard output"

Is there any chance to hide every nohup message?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `eval`?

Comment: What version of `nohup` do you have? I can't reproduce this with 4.1.5.

Comment: I am not sure. I am new to bash. What I try to do is to grep some file for matches. If there any I want to print theme and if there are not, I want to go for else and search on web.

Comment: how to check the version cause when I run nohup --version in console it responds with errors

Comment: I guess you have an old version if it doesn't have --version.

Comment: It must be writing to `/dev/tty` instead of `stdout` or `stderr`. You'll have to use something like `expect` to redirect its output.

Comment: Well I have no message on mac but when I test it on some debian linux the message appears. man nohup says it has --version option..

Comment: I did it on Debian. `nohup --version` says `nohup (GNU coreutils) 8.5`. (`4.1.5` is my bash version, I misread).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick I use is to run `nohup` in a sub-shell and redirect the standard error output of the sub-shell to `/dev/null`:

```
if (nohup grep "'$arg1' '$arg2' [A-Za-z]\+" /tmp/dict.txt & ) 2>/dev/null
then : …whatever…
else : …never executed…
fi
```

However, the exit status of that command is 0, even if the `grep` fails to do anything (mine wrote `grep: /tmp/dict.txt: No such file or directory` in `nohup.out`, for example), but the exit status was still 0, success.  The one disadvantage of the notation used here is that the job is run by the sub-shell, so the main process cannot wait for it to complete.  You can work around that with:

```
(exec nohup grep "'$arg1' '$arg2' [A-Za-z]\+" /tmp/dict.txt ) 2>/dev/null &
```

This gives you the job control information at an interactive terminal; it won't in a non-interactive script, of course.  You could also place the `&` outside the sub-shell and after the error redirection in the first command line, without the `exec`, and the result is essentially the same.

Comment: Yes; I think that braces would also work.  If you don't have the background `&` inside the braces, you need a semicolon before the close brace.  I've always used the explicit sub-shell because if I run `nohup` in background, I have no interest in knowing when it finishes — it'll normally be tomorrow before I look at the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, braces do work. However, a problem arises: you can't get PID of that background process, because all code inside braces is executed in a subshell, therefore you can't simply assign `$!` to a var in the parent shell. My solution to this was to use a temp file:

```
pid_file=$(mktemp)
( nohup sleep 120 & echo $! > "${pid_file}" ) 2> /dev/null
PID=$(cat "${pid_file})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .bashrc

```
function detach { ( nohup $* </dev/null 2>&1 >/dev/null & disown ; sleep 0 ) >/dev/null ; } ; export -f detach
```

Then you can run: detach 
e.g. detach gedit .bashrc

You can also make functions for specific programs, such as:

```
function gedit { ( nohup gedit $* </dev/null 2>&1 >/dev/null & disown ; sleep 0 ) >/dev/null ; } ; export -f gedit
```

The "disown" prevents output when the program ends in the background.

The "sleep 0" causes the prompt to return.